# How to have a positional argument before options in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, arguments, sh, getopts

I want to have a shell script that takes a file name as first positional argument followed by options (`./test.sh <file> [options]`). However, getopts doesn't work when I give a positional argument before options. I have the following code:

```
while getopts "h" opt; do
  case $opt in
    h) 
      echo usage
      ;;
      ;;
  esac
done

echo $1
```

`./test.sh -h` prints `usage` on the shell, but `./test.sh test -h` prints `test` on the shell. So when I give a positional argument before an option it's not doing anything with the option. It does work when having the positional arguments after the option (change `echo $1` to `echo $BASH_ARGV` and the call to `./test.sh -h test`). How can I have the positional argument before the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell builtin getopts does not support reordering the parameters. If you want parameter reordering, you need to use one of the enhanced getopt variants (e.g. gnu getopt or bsd getopt). Please note that the default bsd getopt does not support long options (e.g. when used on Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace "h" to h

```
while getopts h opt; do...
```

And also you have to add minus in your case

```
case "$opt" in
 -h)...
```

If you know, that your [file] will always be present, can you just use

```
filename="$1"
shift
```

And than parse other arguments

Comment: What's the difference between my way of using getopts and yours? Because for the small tests I did they both work the same.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein If you know that the "filename" parameter will be allways present and will be at first place, you can use `shift` as I proposed and than use `getopts`

Comment: I meant the "h" to h and -h part. The filename parameter isn't always present.